# Fetch files from IFS directory file which are less than 120 minutes

Tags: linux, shell, ibm-midrange

I am using shell in an AS400. I need to find all files older than 120 minutes:

```
find . -type f -mmin 120
```

It fails with an error `-mmin is not valid`. Then I tried `-mtime` but since it is days, I can't use a decimal to find files which older than 120 minutes.

I've been unable to think of how to use the -newer option to get this done.

Comment: Your question would be better readeable if you would format the code parts in fixed point font. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: IMO `find . -type f -mmin 120` should give you all entries (files and directories) with modification time **exactly** 120 minutes ago. I do **not** get an error message. What is your `find` version? Mine is _GNU 4.9.0_. `-mmin -120` gives the ones with mod time less than 120 minutes, `-mmin +120` finds those with mod time more than 120 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The -mmin option (and all other time option) have three options. They can be a number (e.g. `120`) for exactly 120 minutes ago. They can also be `+120` for more than 120 minutes and `-120` for less than 120 minutes.

```
find . -mmin +120 -print
```

Note this command also will return `.` if it meets the time criteria. The current directory (`.`) is likely not what you need. You have options.

- `find . -type f -mmin +120 -print` for only regular files.
- `find . -name \*.jpg -mmin +120 -print` for only files ending in `.jpg`.

One more thing, it is considered unsafe to use the output of `find` to run other commands. You will need to use `-print0` to null terminate the files then use `xargs -0` to run the commands safely with special characters.